# Substract two dates in Scala with yyyyMMdd format

Tags: scala, date

I have two dates and I want to obtain the difference of these two dates.

Assuming we have the following :

`dateBefore = 20200310 (yyyyMMdd)`

`dateAfter  = 20200312 (yyyyMMdd)`

The desired result is : `20200311`

Any ideas of the code ?

Comment: Use `java.time` to parse and subtract them. The API is very intuitive, give it a try and if you get stuck edit the question.

Comment: Difference? `20200311` looks more like the average, the middle of the date interval? Voting to close as unclear; please ping me here when you have edited and clarified so I can remove the close vote. Also can the length of the period from before to after be any non-negative number of days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could parse the date string into LocalDate first, so you can play with the time easily using java.time API.

```scala
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import java.time.{ LocalDate, Period }

val format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd")

val dateBefore: LocalDate = LocalDate.parse("20200310", format)
val dateAfter: LocalDate = LocalDate.parse("20200315", format)

val period: Period = Period.between(dateBefore, dateAfter)

period.getYears() // Int = 0
period.getMonths() // Int = 0
period.getDays() // Int = 5
```

or in case you want a list of date between the two..

```scala
val daysDiff = dateAfter.toEpochDay - dateBefore.toEpochDay //Int = 5

(1 until daysDiff).toList // List(1, 2, 3, 4)
  .map(d => dateBefore.plusDays(d).format(format)) //List(20200311, 20200312, 20200313, 20200314)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can uses Regex to format the date then use the java.time._ package to get the differences in days months and years. Also the is time.temporal._ package can be used to get the total number of days months or years

```
import java.time._
import java.time.temporal._

def dateDiff(date1: Int, date2: Int): Unit = {
    val date_pattern = "(\\d{4})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})".r
    val fmt_date1 =  date_pattern.replaceAllIn(date1.toString, "$1-$2-$3")
    val fmt_date2 =  date_pattern.replaceAllIn(date2.toString, "$1-$2-$3")

    val s1 = LocalDate.parse(fmt_date1)
    val s2 = LocalDate.parse(fmt_date2)
    val p = Period.between(s1, s2)

    println(f"""Diff is ${p.getYears()} years ${p.getMonths()} months
            |${p.getDays()} days""".stripMargin.replaceAll("\n", " ")) //Diff is 2 years 0 months 2 days

    println(f"""Diff is ${ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(s1, s2)} years
            |${ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(s1, s2)} months
            |${ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(s1, s2)} days"""
            .stripMargin.replaceAll("\n", " ")) // Diff is 2 years 24 months 733 days
}
```